# How to restore previous version of git with EGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

For example, in local
1st commit: 10am
2nd commit: 11am
3rd commit: 12pm
4th commit: 1pm
After the 4th commit, I found that the code is not working, so, I want to restore to 2nd commit, how to do it?

There are two cases after I restore to 2nd commit:

1. I found the bugs and I think that 3rd and 4th commit is no longer
   working, so I would like to delete the 3rd commit and 4th commit,
   and then commit again for my bug fixing.
2. I fixed the bugs and since the 3rd and 4th commit code is useful, I
   would like to have my 5th commit that is combination of my bug
   fixing at 2nd commit and the 4th commit.

I am new to Git, please help to solve the problem. I am using `Eclipse with EGit` for my Android project.

Comment: answer from Kyralessa may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/undo-last-git-commit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Revert to previous Git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-previous-git-commit)

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to delete commit 3 and 4

If you have not pushed code anywhere, you can use git reset

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

I you have pushed code anywhere

```
git revert HEAD
git revert HEAD~3 
(actually it is head~2, but now head is incremented by 1 in 1st revert)
and then push
```